# passing a class type as a parameter

Tags: c++

I have a setup in my game engine where I can add behavours to game objects. All behaviours are based on the class `AbstractBehaviour`. To easily get access to behaviours from a game object, I am trying to mimic unity's `getComponentOfType<type>()`.

Now for the question:
how can I pass a class type as a parameter to my `GetBehaviourOfType()` function?

What I am trying to achieve in code:

```
AbstractBehaviour* GameObject::GetBehaviourOfType(typeid type)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _behaviours->size(); i++)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<type>(_behaviours[i]) != NULL)
        {
            return _behaviours[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Where `_behaviours` is a vector of abstract behaviours.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Why do you use c++ if it's to use one of it's slowest features? If you want to do what unity does, why not do it in unity?

Comment: because its a school project where we have to write the game in our own c++ engine.

Comment: I think Unreal Engine is in c++, you might want to investigate how they do their thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ differs a lot from C# in that it is a much more static language. There is very little support for Runtime Type Inference in C++, so in general I'd avoid going that route and just design my code in a very strongly typed fashion, avoiding abstract types, within reason.

If you must go that way, your best bet would probably be using a template, however, it will still be a compile-time thing only, you can't really pass a type as a normal function parameter.

```
template<class T>
AbstractBehaviour* GetBehaviourOfType()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _behaviours->size(); i++)
    {
        if (dynamic_cast<T*>(_behaviours[i]) != nullptr)
        {
            return _behaviours[i];
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

// auto behaviour = gameObj.GetBehaviourOfType<PlayerBehaviour>();
```

If you really need the dynamic/runtime variant, then take a look at something like [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info). You might be able to come up with a non-trivial solution using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash table for behaviors and access the elements by their `typeid`:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<const std::type_info*, AbstractBehaviour*> BehaviourHashTable;

// ...

template<typename T>
T* GetBehaviourOfType(void)
{
    if (_behaviours.count(&typeid(T)) != 0){
        return static_cast<T*>(_behaviours[&typeid(T)]);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

This is much faster than using `dynamic_cast`.

Example (where RunBehaviour is a sub-class):

```
AbstractBehaviour* run = GetBehaviorOfType<RunBehaviour>();
```

Insert into the table with:

```
_behaviours[&typeid(*behaviour)] = behaviour;
```

Comment: Impossible to affirm that the hash-table approach is faster than `dynamic_cast` without knowing your compiler internals. The compiler might very well be using a hash-table internally already! Also, your lookup of the table is counter-intuitive. In the worst case it will perform two lookups, one for `count()` and again for `operator[]`. Better to just use `find()` and test the iterator against `end()`, then dereference it.